# Labels into Floating Button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying to insert labels on the side of FABs...
I searched a little and I found the way with LinearLayout and TextView, but I couldn't make it..
I have wrote this until now, but it doesn't show me not even the button..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.nigi.myapplication2.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible">
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB1"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="338dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Do you have any ideas, about what is wrong?? Thank you!!

**UPDATE**
I was a little bit tired yesterday and I didn't saw a lot of thinks..
Thanks for the comments!!
So, I rewrite the LinearLayout part and I make some changes to the java file, but still I have some problems:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible"

    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement View.OnClickListener{
private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
private FloatingActionButton fab,fab1,fab2;
private Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;
LinearLayout linear1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);

    linear1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);

    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(this);
    linear1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.fab:

            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.fab1:

            Log.d("Raj", "Fab 1");
            break;
        case R.id.fab2:

            Log.d("Raj", "Fab 2");
            break;
    }
}

public void animateFAB(){

    if(isFabOpen){

        fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
        linear1.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab1.setClickable(false);
        fab2.setClickable(false);
        isFabOpen = false;
        Log.d("Raj", "close");

    } else {

        fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fab1.startAnimation(fab_open);
        linear1.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab1.setClickable(true);
        fab2.setClickable(true);
        isFabOpen = true;
        Log.d("Raj","open");

    }
}
}
```

[and the screenshot after the changes is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koXUT.png)

Any ideas what's wrong?? Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Anyone who can help???

Comment: Can you remove the old code and just show the current one? Also, can you provide the expected behavior ("but still I have some problems" is not very descriptive...).

Comment: As you can see the image I have upload, you will see that the buttons appears on different places... On original xml, there is no LinearLayout and TextView and on java file it is there is no LinearLayout and where I write linear1, originally it was fab2....

Comment: You gave one of the buttons width and for the other you didn't. Another thing is that on of them has a layout_marginBottom="90dp" and the other doesn't. I suggest you make sure they have the same definitions if you want them to be in same place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't get it...
On both I have android:layout_width="wrap_content" and on the other one I have android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"..

Comment: I was referring to android:layout_width="338dp". Make sure the code in your post matches the one you have on your computer.

Comment: Oh!!! This?? this is the big button and for that reason it has different size... But I don't think that this is the problem... Thank you for the comments..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is unrelated, but this `LinearLayout` seems wrong:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible">
```

You have an invisible view that takes the whole screen and has no id, so I guess you don't turn it to visible late.